# Issue of Authentication using GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to authenticate a user by GitHub API.
I've tried on two methods,  Authentication via username and password and via personal access token(PAT) like this;

```
curl -u devmania1223 https://api.github.com/user   /*via username and password*/

curl -u ghp_I60uniHdf6UKDCkyde1InP7kwRwsw2fD0wx https://api.github.com/user   /*via personal access token*/
```

Inputted username and password, PAT correctly, but the response is not right.

```
{
  "message": "Requires authentication",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#get-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

So, What's wrong with curl command?

Answer (score 1):

Try and use the token as password:

```
curl -i -u your_username:$token https://api.github.com/users/octocat
```

Don't forget the other option: `gh` (the GitHub [`cli/cli`](https://github.com/cli/cli)), using [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)

```sh
# authenticate against github.com by reading the token from a file
$ gh auth login --with-token < mytoken.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your personal access token is *55a6f290558d11ecbeaf787b8ab956b4*. Now, make a request using the GitHub API, put the token into the "Authorization" header:

```
/usr/bin/curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 55a6f290558d11ecbeaf787b8ab956b4" https://api.github.com/user
```

Why? Well, the type of token that GitHub gives to you is called "OAuth 2.0" token, and you just have to use it this way.